# Get a list of files in an IIS6 website

Tags: iis, iis-6

Is there a way to get an exhaustive list of files in an IIS6 website?

Comment: I'm really after virtual-physical path mappings. Can the metabase be examined to work out which virtual directory is causing a certain file to be part of the site?

Comment: you should edit your original question and add your comment to that instead.

Comment: I can't edit it - I think because I didn't create a user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried: **iisvdir /query {site name}**?

This will give you all of the virtual directories of a site and the physical location of those virtual directories.